# Generate Sequence Number on similar values from dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

Trying to fetch a sequence number on similar group (Fuzzy) of values.

Input data frame:

```
KeyName          KeyCompare           Source
PapasMrtemis     PapasMrtemis          S1
PapasMrtemis     Pappas, Mrtemis       S1
Pappas, Mrtemis  PapasMrtemis          S2
Pappas, Mrtemis  Pappas, Mrtemis       S2
Micheal          Micheal               S1
RCore            Core                  S1
RCore            Core,R                S2
```

How I can group similar values into one set. Names may come similar or unique from different systems.

I need output as below, please help!

Output data frame:

```
KeyName          KeyCompare           Source      KeyId
PapasMrtemis     PapasMrtemis          S1          1
PapasMrtemis     Pappas, Mrtemis       S1          1 
Pappas, Mrtemis  PapasMrtemis          S2          1 
Pappas, Mrtemis  Pappas, Mrtemis       S2          1 
Micheal          Micheal               S1          2
RCore            Core                  S1          3
RCore            Core,R                S2          3
```

Comment: Sounds like a good task for [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher).

Comment: Also, does `AB`, for example, count as similar to `A` and `B` as well?

Comment: @Adi, What is the logic/rule for "similar"? In above sample it looks like words with all same chars; but since it is sample that sounds too naive. In real case, there will be complex terms. So, which string terms do you call "similar"?

Comment: @Azhar Khan Just as sample kept same characters, similar words like James, Jame, Jam.

Comment: @Adi, please update question with some values from your real dataset and expected output. The sample is oversimplified. This will help to decide the solution to propose.

Comment: @Azhar Khan updated.

Comment: @Azhar Khan, Your code is working. I did some changes on cross join, it is taking maximum 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

the **Previous version** will work if you sort the dataframe by doing `df.sort_values(by='KeyName')`

Previous version:

Let's import the library `difflib` and calculate the `matching ratio` by using the function `SequenceMatcher(a,b).ratio` and increment `keyId` when that ratio is lower than `0.5`:

```
import difflib

KeyId=[]

KeyId.append(1)

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if difflib.SequenceMatcher(a = df['KeyName'][i], b = df['KeyName'][i-1]).ratio() >= 0.5:
        KeyId.append(KeyId[i-1])
    else:
        KeyId.append(KeyId[i-1]+1)
df['KeyId'] = KeyId
```

**Output**

```
>>> df
KeyName          KeyCompare           Source      KeyId
PapasMrtemis     PapasMrtemis          S1          1
PapasMrtemis     Pappas, Mrtemis       S1          1 
Pappas, Mrtemis  PapasMrtemis          S2          1 
Pappas, Mrtemis  Pappas, Mrtemis       S2          1 
Micheal          Micheal               S1          2
RCore            Core                  S1          3
RCore            Core,R                S2          3
```

## New version

Let's import `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib`

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
```

And let's set up three fucntions:

This function returns true if a matching word exists within a `list`:

```
def exist_matchings_of_in(word, list_words, precision):
    return any(SequenceMatcher(a = word, b = e).ratio() >= precision for e in list_words)
```

And this one returns  the first matched word in a `list`:

```
def first_matched_word(word, list_words, precision):
    matche=''
    if exist_matchings_of_in(word, list_words, precision):
        for i in range(len(list_words)):
            if SequenceMatcher(a = word, b = list_words[i]).ratio() >= precision:
                matche=list_words[i]
                break
    return matche
```

And this function returns the `index` of the first matched word:

```
def matched_word_idx(word, list_words, precision):
    matched_word=first_matched_word(word, list_words, precision)
    idx = list_words.index(matched_word)
    
    return idx
```

And the following fuction uses the aboves ones to return the `list` of `KeyId`:

```
def get_KeyId(list_words, precision):
    
    KeyId=[]
    KeyId.append(1)

    if SequenceMatcher(a = list_words[0], b = list_words[1]).ratio() >= precision:
        KeyId.append(1)
    else:
        KeyId.append(2)

    for i in range(2, len(list_words)):
        
        if exist_matchings_of_in(list_words[i], list_words[:i], precision):
            
            KeyId.append(KeyId[matched_word_idx(list_words[i], list_words[:i], precision)])
            
        else:
            
            KeyId.append(max(KeyId)+1)
            
    return KeyId
```

So let's use this last function to get `keyId` list:

```
# We can play on the precision value in order to get the desired matches

KeyId=get_KeyId(df['KeyName'], precision=0.53)


df['KeyId']=KeyId
```

Comment: df['Id'] = [x[0] for x in df['Name']] , How this works on Name column iteration from a dataframe. getting error Column is not iterable. I need it in Pyspark. Can you please suggest in spark.

Comment: You can do instead of that : `df['Id'] = [df['Name'][i][0] for i in range(len(df))]`, let me know if it worked @Adi

Comment: even in pandas after getting id column how it generates number by a group. pls help.

Comment: not worked getting Id as 1 for all the column values.

Comment: @Adi please take a look at the full code in my new edits and let me know

Comment: @Adi on my side it worked well

Comment: I updated the question please check, It's not same not characters in every group. as a sample I kept that

Comment: @Adi what would be the `Id` when `Name` = Hilo, and `Source`=S2 ?

Comment: I updated more similar data as per the requirement. basically, names are coming from the different source systems, I am doing union of those. then applied fuzzy match with one value compares other values of same column.Now I want to add Id column (similar group need to have incremental number) for similar values irrespective of source.

Comment: @Adi Thanks, now I think your question is clear

Comment: any luck please.

Comment: @Adi Please take a look at my `new edits`

Comment: Thanks a lot. excellent, it worked with pandas dataframe.

Comment: Khaled Dellal, Same code not working now, if I take only few values it is working. Last day it worked same data same code.

Comment: @Adi can you provide the error message please ?

Comment: Khaled Delall, No error is there, but not working on multiple sources with good amount of data around 7k

Comment: Hi @Adi , can you provide an example of two consecutive rows where the code didn't work please ?

Comment: Please check this. 1WalterCraig,S1,5842/n1CraigPeine,S1,6086/n1WalteCraig,S2,7105/n5WalterCraig,S2,7105
I have almost 7k rows for this match similarities. /n means row separator.

Comment: 1WalterCraig,1WalteCraig,5WalterCraig are similar here, not same group id I got. Can you please let me know. Code is working. FYI, If I take only these values It is working on different sources giving same group id. It is hard to find where exactly disturbing the flow.

Comment: with Levenshtein distance not generating same group id irrespective of sources.

Comment: Thanks for providing those details @Adi , I understood where is issue, I am preparing a new update, will let you know asap

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know, I am not a such good expert python.

Comment: Hi @Adi , please take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Hi @Khaled Dellal, getting type error range index not callable.

Comment: Its working but taking huge time more than 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

Use [levenshtein#distance](https://maxbachmann.github.io/Levenshtein/levenshtein.html#distance) to know similar words. Use a configurable parameter like threshold with which the similarity can be controlled.

The logic is:

- Compare each term with all other terms and compute L-distance. This way you get pairwise distance between all terms. Drop pairs below threshold.
- Group similar terms. For this, collect all pairs and flatten them. The resulting group it all similar terms.
- Assign serial number to each group. This can be easily done using Window and row_number() utils.
- Finally, explode the groups with serial number as "id".

**Note:** Added [pandas_udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) for vectorised processing. It will be little faster than regular UDF; however the logic uses `pd.apply()`, which iterates row by row because the [levenshtein distance API](https://maxbachmann.github.io/Levenshtein/levenshtein.html#distance) works on individual strings - not on vector.

```py
# !pip install python-Levenshtein

# pandas_udf to compute Levenshtein distance
@F.pandas_udf(IntegerType())
def get_lev_dist_batch(col1: pd.DataFrame, col2: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
  import pandas as pd
  import Levenshtein as lev
  tmp_df  = pd.DataFrame({"KeyName1": col1.KeyName, "KeyName2": col2.KeyName})
  tmp_df["distance"] = tmp_df.apply(lambda row: lev.distance(row["KeyName1"], row["KeyName2"]), axis=1)
  return tmp_df["distance"]

# UDF to compute Levenshtein distance
@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def get_lev_dist(col1, col2):
  import Levenshtein as lev
  return lev.distance(col1.KeyName, col2.KeyName)

# Sample dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["PapasMrtemis","S1"],["Pappas, Mrtemis","S1"],["Pappas, Mr. temis","S2"],["Micheal","S2"],["RCore","S1"],["Core","S1"],["Core,R","S2"]], schema=["KeyName", "Source"])

# Combine KeyName and Source into a tuple
df = df.withColumn("KS", F.struct("KeyName", "Source")) \
       .drop("KeyName", "Source")

# Compute distance between pair created with cross join.
df = df.crossJoin(df.withColumnRenamed("KS", "KS2"))
df = df.withColumn("distance", get_lev_dist_batch(F.col("KS"), F.col("KS2")))

# Filter pair below similarity threshold and group the similar pair
similarity_distance_threshold = 4
df = df.filter(F.col("distance") <= similarity_distance_threshold)
df = df.groupBy("KS") \
       .agg(F.collect_set("KS2").alias("similar")) \
      .drop("KS")

# Eliminate duplicate and empty groups
df = df.crossJoin(df.withColumnRenamed("similar", "similar2"))
df = df.withColumn("common_count", F.size(F.array_intersect(F.col("similar"), F.col("similar2"))))
df = df.filter(F.col("common_count") > 0)
df = df.groupBy("similar") \
       .agg(F.array_sort(F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_set("similar2")))).alias("similar_names")) \
       .drop("similar")
df = df.groupBy("similar_names") \
       .count().drop("count")

# Assign serial number to each group and expand the groups
df = df.withColumn("dummy", F.lit(0))
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.orderBy("dummy")
df = df.withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(w)) \
       .drop("dummy")
df = df.withColumn("KS", F.explode("similar_names")) \
       .drop("similar_names")

# Separate out KeyName and Source from tuple
df = df.withColumn("KeyName", F.col("KS").getField("KeyName")) \
       .withColumn("Source", F.col("KS").getField("Source")) \
       .drop("KS")
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------------+------+
| id|          KeyName|Source|
+---+-----------------+------+
|  1|             Core|    S1|
|  1|           Core,R|    S2|
|  1|            RCore|    S1|
|  2|          Micheal|    S2|
|  3|     PapasMrtemis|    S1|
|  3|Pappas, Mr. temis|    S2|
|  3|  Pappas, Mrtemis|    S1|
+---+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: @Adi, Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: not completely, I will do it. as of now I am going with pandas. I will use this solution. In long run I want to use spark.

Comment: It worked but how can I get source column as well without joining. Can you please add that.

Comment: @Azar Khan, and also can we avoid udf.. taking huge time.

Comment: Updated the answer to include Source column. The UDF can be replaced with pandas_udf; but the core distance API works on individual strings, hence vectorised solution does not look possible here. https://maxbachmann.github.io/Levenshtein/levenshtein.html#distance

Comment: Added pandas_udf for vectorised processing. It will be little faster than regular UDF; however the logic uses `pd.apply()`, which again iterates row by row because the core distance API works on individual strings - not on vector.

Comment: still taking more time. rows are 7k. It took 20 min.

Comment: ,I am trying with list Comparisions with distance even that also taking more time.